# Navbar menu issue when click on a dropdown

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I use boostrap 5

I have a navbar with a dropdown menu.

When i put mouse over Project, menu appear, but if i click on project, like a second menu open.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto bg-light pe-4 py-3 py-lg-0">
        <a href="index.html" class="nav-item nav-link">welcom</a>
        <a href="about.html" class="nav-item nav-link">About </a>
        <div class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Project</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu bg-light border-0 m-0">
                <a href="electronic.html" class="dropdown-item">Electronic</a>
                <a href="industrial.html" class="dropdown-item ">Industrial</a>
                <a href="diving.html" class="dropdown-item">Diving</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="contact.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see live the issue at
https://htmlcodex.com/demo/?item=2574

when you click on **project**

If I remove data-bs-toggle="dropdown" problem is not there anymore, but on mobile, I don't see any menu

don't have done any js modification

css is there
https://pastebin.com/XCd1vMud

Comment: The default bootstrap functionality is based on click. It seems you have overridden by js to show the dropdown menu on hover. So you need to stop the click on the Pages menu item for the large screens, only. For mobiles screens it is working as expected

Comment: don't think it's possible. will search the standard way to do it... no problem to change my code

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.